# Adding a column into a Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Stackblitz link for you all: https://stackblitz.com/edit/voltagery-capstone

You can see the design that I am going to.

I need some help trying to design this homepage for my capstone class. I have been trying to figure this out using a Jumbotron and having a text overtop of it. Any help would be awesome.

Nic [What I want the homepage to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTNHu.png)

<--------------------------Updated Code------------------------->
How can I make 4 separate rows inside of this one column

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <div class="bg bg-left">
            <h2>Create your snippet's HTML, CSS and Javascript in the editor tabs</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: This site is recognized to solve problems or challenges, not to solve your task. give some of the code you have tried and ask for help, not ask to make whole code for me

Comment: Well, I just needed help making the column on top of the Jumbotron. I don't need the whole site just need to set up the jumbotron with a column on the right side.

Comment: which column do you want to add on top of jumbotron?

Comment: Nisharg,

I appreciate your time, and I have completely revamped the code since I couldn't figure out the jumbotron. I split the layout into two columns, and I am trying to add rows to the columns to insert data. 

     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
         <div class="bg bg-left">
          <h2>Sample Text</h2>
         </div>

How could I go about adding four rows into this column specifically?

Comment: what? do you want to create a row? it's easy to do!! like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/voltagery-capstone-hyjnx8?file=app%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

Comment: please explain with images in the post so, it will crystal clear!! where you want to insert HTML, how many rows in which place, with images!! so I understand properly because I can't understand right now what you want to do